# How to send a REST WS parameter parsing exception message back to the client?

Tags: java, json, rest, jax-rs, http-status-codes

I've got a web service whose parameter is parsed into a Java object. The parameter is a json string:

```
@GET
@Path("myService")
public void myService(@QueryParam("a") MyClass myVal) {
    //do something
}
```

In the Java object class, the method fromString is implemented

```
class MyClass {
    public int foo;
    public int bar;

   /** Deserializes an Object of class MyClass from its JSON representation */
   public static MyClass fromString(String jsonRepresentation) {
           ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); //Jackson's JSON marshaller
           MyClass o= null;
           try {
                   o = mapper.readValue(jsonRepresentation, MyClass.class );
           } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new WebApplicationException(Response
                .status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(e.getMessage())
                .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build());
           }
           return o;
   }
}
```

In the case where a json -> java parsing exception happens, my client gets a HTTP 404 response, instead of the HTTP 400 "bad request" that is implemented in the code.

Is this a normal behaviour?

Comment: Is the parsing exception an `IOException` or a subclass?

Comment: @Tichodroma The exception type is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException

Comment: I'm sorry, I corrected the posted code. I'd like to handle all type of exceptions.

Comment: If this is your, then every exception thrown by the `mapper.readValue` call must result in a `400 Bad Request`. Try to debug into your application and check what is happening.

Comment: At the moment of throwing the WebApplicationException, an InvocationTargetException is raised!

Comment: Throw the `WebApplicationException` from the JAX-RS class.

Comment: I cannot put the POJO class that contains the fromString method inside the JAX-RS class

Comment: If you're getting a 404 the problem is somewhere else. For better help, post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with the request you are sending. Personally, the first thing I would do is to redesign this to where JSON is _not_ put in a query param.

Comment: The request is quite simple. One request parameter is a json object. When there is a spelling mistake in the json for example, the exception I mentioned before is raised. When the json is correct, everything is OK. I cannot redesign the request parameters because the json is a large complex object.